# Whose responsibility is it to delete

Tags: c++, memory-management

In C++, whose responsibility is it to delete members of a class: the class, or the creator of an instance of that class?
For example, in the following code:

```
class B {
  public:
    B(int x) { num = x; }
    int num;
};

class A {
  public:
    A(B* o) { obj = o; }
    B* obj;
};

int main(void) {
  A myA(new B(3));
  return 0;
}
```

Should `main` delete the instance of `B`, or should `A`'s destructor delete its local variable `obj`? Is this true in most cases, and in which cases if any is it not?

Comment: This is what a destructor is for. So, to answer the question, the class, when the destructor is called. If you use smart pointers, neither has to worry about it.

Comment: That would be your design choice. The only enforced rule is this: your program must call `delete` for each and every `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic question of ownership. If every `A` should own a `B` (as in, there should be a new `B` created when the `A` is created, that should also be destroyed be the `A` is destroyed, then you'd normally make `A` responsible for creating and destroying the instance of B:

```
class B { 
    int num;
public:
    B(int x) : num(x) {}
};

class A { 
    B *obj;
public:
    A(int value) : obj(new B(value)) {}
    ~A() { delete B; }
};
```

In such a case, however, chances are pretty good that `A` should just be written like:

```
class A {
    B obj;
public:
    A(int v) : obj(v) {}
};

int main() { 
    A a(3);
    return 0;
}
```

This way, the instance of `B` will be created and destroyed automatically, without any intervention on your part at all.

Comment: Don't forget the Rule of Three.

Comment: @chris: yes -- part of the reason for just doing it right, and aggregating an instance of B directly in A and being done with it.

Comment: I should also point out that ownership can be transferred if required.  At the end of the day it's up to you, as a programmer, to decide who owns what, whether that ownership is for life, or whether that ownership is transferred depending on application state.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always `A` should manage it's members as this is what RAII is based off of. Use `unique_ptr` when you can.

If it doesn't manage it's data then it should use a different smart pointer, specifically `shared_ptr`. This shifts the responsibility to the `shared_ptr`, which is much less error prone than a vanilla pointer.

And of course, the preferred way is to use no pointers at all. Why are you calling `new` in the first place?

Comment: Why am I calling new: in order to ask this question. I'm coming to C++ from java and C, and I want to understand everything. I've never heard of smart pointers or RAII, but I'll look them up. Thanks!

Comment: @Robz - In C++ you hardly ever call `new`. C++ and Java are *very* different languages.

Comment: @BoPersson, what do you write in C++ that you hardly ever call new?  :)